# How to sort S3 CSV File using AWS GLUE

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm relatively new to AWS glue and spark. I'd like to sort a csv file by user ID in S3. I'm trying out the script below, but it's not sorting the file.Can someone please help me in this?

```
import sys
import math
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import asc

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME','DESTINATION_PATH', 'SOURCE_PATH'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options("s3", connection_options = {"paths": [args['SOURCE_PATH']]}, format="csv", format_options = {"withHeader": True});

print("records read from s3 store")
print(dyf.count())

file_size = 10000
n_partitions = int(math.ceil(dyf.count() / float(file_size))) 

print("splitting file into partitions")
print(n_partitions)
sort_dataframe = dyf.toDF().orderBy("user_id")
print(sort_dataframe.show())
df_dataframe = sort_dataframe.repartition(n_partitions)
ddf_dataframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(sort_dataframe, glueContext, "ddf_dataframe")

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = ddf_dataframe, connection_type = "s3", format = "csv", connection_options = {"path": args['DESTINATION_PATH']}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4",format_options = {"withHeader": True})

print("records processing complete")

job.commit()
```

Comment: To verify, is the output of the following correctly sorted by user_id? `sort_dataframe = dyf.toDF().orderBy("user_id")
print(sort_dataframe.show())`

Comment: Yes, The above statement's output is correctly sorted by user id, but the data becomes unsorted after repartition.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting it, then immediately shuffling everything randomly to other partitions by repartitioning. Do a `dyf.toDF().repartition(n_partitions).sortWithinPartitions("user_id")`. You will get the full range of user ids in each file, but within each file every row is sorted by user id.

If you are querying by athena that is actually good as you can query all files in parallel but the query will be able to zoom in on just the portion of the file with the user ids you are filtering by very quickly (if you are using parquet at least).

If that is not suitable try `dyf.toDF().repartitionByRange(n_partitions, "user_id")`. That will require it to sample the user_id and make an educated guess at how to distribute the user ids between files, therefore the files may not be perfectly evenly sized, but each file will have a different set of user ids and no files will have overlapping ranges of user ids.